# ordering multiple legends - changes legend style

Tags: r, ggplot2, rect, geom

I have a plot with a coloured background (geom_rect) and a coloured line (geom_line). I am trying to maintain consistent legend order: o2 above temperature, or temperature above o2. The key is consistency.

I have tried using guides(col = guide_legend(order = 2), fill = guide_legend(order = 1)) and this changes the order BUT also changes the style of the legends completely from a gradient to a made up series of specific values.

How can I set order while keeping the gradient colour schemes for the legends? changing the position of the code within the ggplot call doesn't change the result.

```
legend_t = parse(text='"Temperature ("^o*"C)" ')
legend_o2 = parse(text='"DO2 (mmol m" ^-3*")" ')

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = rects, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = o2_fill),
            inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red", na.value = NA, limits = c(30,250)) +
  geom_line(data = plot, aes(x = tf/60, y = Depth*-1, col = Temperature), size = 2) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red", na.value = NA, limits = c(3,30)) +
  labs(fill = legend_o2) +
  labs(col = legend_t) +
  xlab("Dive Duration (minutes)") + ylab("Depth (meters)") +
  #scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1600,0), breaks=seq(-1600,0,100)) + # sets axis tick marks on y axis scale
  #scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,round_any(max(dive$tf/60),10, f = ceiling)), breaks=seq(0,round_any(max(dive$tf/60),10, f = ceiling),5)) +
  #coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1300,0)) + #zooms in so the coloured background doesn't get cut off
  guides(col = guide_legend(order = 2), fill = guide_legend(order = 1)) #set legend order
```

here's what the result is without using guides: legend is a gradient
[image: legend is a gradient]

here's the result using guides: legend order consistent but style completely changed
[image: legend order consistent but style completely changed]
In order to reproduce, I put some # on the scaling and zoom, and here's a small sample of the data:

```
> print(rects[c(1:10),])
   xmin xmax       ymin       ymax  o2_fill
1  -Inf  Inf   0.000000  -0.505760 200.7229
2  -Inf  Inf  -0.505760  -1.555855 200.7229
3  -Inf  Inf  -1.555855  -2.667682 200.7930
4  -Inf  Inf  -2.667682  -3.856280 200.8371
5  -Inf  Inf  -3.856280  -5.140361 200.8713
6  -Inf  Inf  -5.140361  -6.543034 200.9002
7  -Inf  Inf  -6.543034  -8.092519 200.9263
8  -Inf  Inf  -8.092519  -9.822750 200.9506
9  -Inf  Inf  -9.822750 -11.773680 200.9745
10 -Inf  Inf -11.773680 -13.991040 201.0089

> print(plot[c(1:10),])
              Date_time Depth Temperature DeepDiveNo   tf       o2
 1: 2016-06-08 10:54:00   9.5       29.15          1 4815 200.9745
 2: 2016-06-08 09:33:45  10.5       29.15          1    0 200.9745
 3: 2016-06-08 09:34:00  13.5       28.85          1   15 201.0697
 4: 2016-06-08 10:53:45  14.5       28.95          1 4800 201.0697
 5: 2016-06-08 10:53:30  18.5       28.20          1 4785 204.0405
 6: 2016-06-08 09:34:15  19.0       28.15          1   30 204.0405
 7: 2016-06-08 10:53:15  23.5       27.35          1 4770 208.8913
 8: 2016-06-08 09:34:30  24.5       27.20          1   45 208.8913
 9: 2016-06-08 10:53:00  27.0       27.15          1 4755 210.4293
10: 2016-06-08 09:34:45  28.0       27.15          1   60 210.4293
```

Comment: There are different `guide_xxx`s, e.g. the default for `scale_fill_gradient` is `guide_colorbar`, i.e. try with `guide_colorbar(order = 1)`...

Comment: Thanks @stefan worked perfectly.
swapped the last line for guides(col = guide_colourbar(order = 1))